# Serializing entity collections in JavaScript to send via SOAP call

Tags: xml, soap, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

Currently trying to serialize an EntityCollection in order to send selected records to a custom action through client side interaction.  Right now, sending the EntityCollection itself has been troublesome.  Any ideas?

Comment: can you clarify a few things: what do you mean by "sending the EntityCollection itself has been troublesome"?  what field are you asking about the max length of?  Is there a reason you couldn't do a "RetrieveMultiple" OData call, and have that trigger the plugin?

Comment: I had issues figuring out the XML serialization.  User selects the intersect entity records they are wanting processed from an fetched collection.  No fields are changing/updating. The field I was inquiring about was inputParameter string field of custom actions/workflows.  It's been figured out though, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out how it is expecting to be serialized, in case anyone else has issues with this in the future.

```
<a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
          <b:key>BusinessEntityCollection</b:key>
          <b:value i:type="a:EntityCollection">
            <a:Entities>
              <a:Entity>
                <a:Attributes>
                  <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                    <b:key>webresourceid</b:key>
                    <b:value i:type="z:guid">02fe0b47-8800-e511-80ef-c4346bada558</b:value>
                  </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                  <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                    <b:key>name</b:key>
                    <b:value i:type="c:string" xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">ryr_formexperiment.crmform.min.js</b:value>
                  </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                  <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                    <b:key>content</b:key>
                    <b:value i:type="c:string" xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">Ly9yeXJfZm9ybWV4cGVyaW1lbnQuY3JtZm9ybS5taW4uanM=</b:value>
                  </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                  <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                    <b:key>webresourcetype</b:key>
                    <b:value i:type="a:OptionSetValue">
                      <a:Value>3</a:Value>
                    </b:value>
                  </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                </a:Attributes>
                <a:EntityState i:nil="true" />
                <a:FormattedValues>
                  <a:KeyValuePairOfstringstring>
                    <b:key>webresourcetype</b:key>
                    <b:value>Script (JScript)</b:value>
                  </a:KeyValuePairOfstringstring>
                </a:FormattedValues>
                <a:Id>02fe0b47-8800-e511-80ef-c4346bada558</a:Id>
                <a:KeyAttributes xmlns:c="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/7.1/Contracts" />
                <a:LogicalName>webresource</a:LogicalName>
                <a:RelatedEntities />
                <a:RowVersion>1308124</a:RowVersion>
              </a:Entity>
            </a:Entities>
            <a:EntityName>webresource</a:EntityName>
            <a:MinActiveRowVersion>-1</a:MinActiveRowVersion>
            <a:MoreRecords>false</a:MoreRecords>
            <a:PagingCookie><cookie page="1"><webresourceid last="{02FE0B47-8800-E511-80EF-C4346BADA558}" first="{02FE0B47-8800-E511-80EF-C4346BADA558}" /></cookie></a:PagingCookie>
            <a:TotalRecordCount>-1</a:TotalRecordCount>
            <a:TotalRecordCountLimitExceeded>false</a:TotalRecordCountLimitExceeded>
          </b:value>
        </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
```